# Code structure for tree representation with multiple types (classes) of nodes and circular dependencies

Tags: python, tree, classes

I am developing a piece of code around a tree structure. The tree can do a few things - one of them being its ability to serialize & de-serialize its data. There are multiple different types of nodes, e.g. `NodeA` and `NodeB`, each represented by a class. Different types of nodes may have significantly different functionality and may hold different types of data. As a common base, all node classes inherit from a "base" `Node` class. Any given type of node can be at the root of the tree. A simplified example of the envisioned structure looks as follows:

```py
from typing import Dict, List
from abc import ABC

class NodeABC(ABC):
    pass

class Node(NodeABC):
    subtype = None
    def __init__(self, nodes: List[NodeABC]):
        self._nodes = nodes
    def as_serialized(self) -> Dict:
        return {"nodes": [node.as_serialized() for node in self._nodes], "subtype": self.subtype}
    @classmethod
    def from_serialized(cls, subtype: str, nodes: List[Dict], **kwargs):
        nodes = [cls.from_serialized(**node) for node in nodes]
        if subtype == NodeA.subtype:
            return NodeA(**kwargs, nodes = nodes)
        elif subtype == NodeB.subtype:
            return NodeB(**kwargs, nodes = nodes)

class NodeA(Node):
    subtype = "A"
    def __init__(self, foo: int, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._foo = foo * 2
    def as_serialized(self) -> Dict:
        return {"foo": self._foo // 2, **super().as_serialized()}

class NodeB(Node):
    subtype = "B"
    def __init__(self, bar: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._bar = bar + "!"
    def as_serialized(self) -> Dict:
        return {"bar": self._bar[:-1], **super().as_serialized()}

demo = {
    "subtype": "A",
    "foo": 3,
    "nodes": [
        {
            "subtype": "B",
            "bar": "ghj",
            "nodes": []
        },
        {
            "subtype": "A",
            "foo": 7,
            "nodes": []
        },
    ]
}

assert demo == Node.from_serialized(**demo).as_serialized()
```

Bottom line: It works. The problem: There are "circular" dependencies between the actual node types `NodeA`/`NodeB` and the base `Node` class. If all of this code resides in a single Python file, it works fine. However, if I try to move each class to a separate file, the Python interpreter will become unhappy because of (theoretically required) circular imports. The actual classes are really big, so I would like to structure my code a bit.

Question: A common wisdom says that if circular imports / dependencies become a topic of debate, then the code's design / structure sucks and is at fault in the first place. I'd agree with that but I really do not have many good ideas of how to improve the above.

I am aware that I could eliminate the circular import "limitation" by doing a "manual run-time import" at least for one part of the circle plus some botching, but this is something that I'd like to avoid ...

---

**CONTEXT**

I have been developing the [zugbruecke Python module](https://github.com/pleiszenburg/zugbruecke).

> It allows to call routines in Windows DLLs from Python code running on Unices / Unix-like systems such as Linux, MacOS or BSD. zugbruecke is designed as a drop-in replacement for Python's standard library's ctypes module. zugbruecke is built on top of Wine. A stand-alone Windows Python interpreter launched in the background is used to execute the called DLL routines.

Its code for synchronizing both `ctypes` datatypes and `ctypes` data has become a bit old and dusty and could use some serious refactoring. Its current form really is not object oriented can be found [here](https://github.com/pleiszenburg/zugbruecke/blob/ec34fc308d4f8dcb11b5c99ab878ccc8b8b08f66/src/zugbruecke/core/data/arg_contents.py) (data type definitions), [here](https://github.com/pleiszenburg/zugbruecke/blob/ec34fc308d4f8dcb11b5c99ab878ccc8b8b08f66/src/zugbruecke/core/data/arg_contents.py) (actual data, mostly), [here](https://github.com/pleiszenburg/zugbruecke/blob/ec34fc308d4f8dcb11b5c99ab878ccc8b8b08f66/src/zugbruecke/core/data/mem_definition.py) (pointer synchronization definitions) and [here](https://github.com/pleiszenburg/zugbruecke/blob/ec34fc308d4f8dcb11b5c99ab878ccc8b8b08f66/src/zugbruecke/core/data/mem_contents.py) (actual pointer synchronization). An early **sketch** of how I'd like to introduce proper object orientation (and some sort of a proper file structure) can be found [here](https://github.com/pleiszenburg/zugbruecke/blob/ec34fc308d4f8dcb11b5c99ab878ccc8b8b08f66/src/zugbruecke/core/data/definition.py). The above example is an oversimplified version of my actual sketch.

Answer (score 1):

You could separate your definition of a Node from the serialization process, which allows for the dependency order of (node serialization) -> (node implementation) -> (node base). This also reduces the amount of `super` juggling that you need to perform in each subclass.

If you wanted to further lighten up the specific node types, you could also remove the need for `**kwargs` by instantiating the objects using a dictionary that doesn't contain the entries for "subtype" or "nodes".

```
from typing import Dict, List, Optional
from abc import ABC

# node.py
class Node(ABC):
    nodes:List['Node']
    subtype:Optional[str] = None

    def serialize(self) -> Dict:
        raise NotImplementedError()

# node_a.py (depends on node)
class NodeA(Node):
    subtype = "A"
    def __init__(self, foo: int, **kwargs):
        self._foo = foo * 2
    def serialize(self) -> Dict:
        return {"foo": self._foo // 2}

# node_b.py ( depends on node)
class NodeB(Node):
    subtype = "B"
    def __init__(self, bar: str, **kwargs):
        self._bar = bar + "!"
    def serialize(self) -> Dict:
        return {"bar": self._bar[:-1]}

# node_serialization.py ( depends on node_a, node_b )
NODE_TYPES = { 
    nodeclass.subtype:nodeclass
    for nodeclass in [NodeA,NodeB]
}

def deserialize(serialized_node: Dict) -> Node:
    node = NODE_TYPES[serialized_node['subtype']](**serialized_node)
    node.nodes = [ deserialize(node) for node in serialized_node['nodes'] ]
    return node

def serialize(node:Node) -> Dict:
    return {
        **node.serialize(),
        'nodes': [ serialize(node) for node in node.nodes ],
        'subtype': node.subtype
    }

# usage
original = {
    "subtype": "A",
    "foo": 3,
    "nodes": [
        {
            "subtype": "B",
            "bar": "ghj",
            "nodes": []
        },
        {
            "subtype": "A",
            "foo": 7,
            "nodes": []
        },
    ]
}

assert original == serialize(deserialize(original))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Hmm simply moving the `deserialize` method outside of the class and into a sort of independent function kind of solves the issue, yes. I honestly did not like that ... it kind of feels wrong because in my real code, it's not only one single method like this that would have to be moved outside of the class.

Comment: FYI, I just added a context section to my question for further details. See the link to my sketch. Maybe this helps to draw some additional light onto the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Python class instances include the attribute `__class__`.  `Node.as_serialized()` uses `self.__class__.__module__` and `self.__class__.__name__` to serialize a node's subtype and to recreate the node when deserializing. Now, `Node.from_serialized()` doesn't need to reference the other Node classes, so there isn't a circular import problem.

```
import sys

class Node:
    def __init__(self, nodes):
        self._nodes = nodes

    def as_serialized(self):
        return {"nodes": [node.as_serialized() for node in self._nodes],
                "subtype": (self.__class__.__module__, self.__class__.__name__)}
    
    @classmethod
    def from_serialized(cls, subtype, nodes, **kwargs):
        nodes = [cls.from_serialized(**node) for node in nodes]
        
        module, klass = subtype
        
        return getattr(sys.modules[module], klass)(**kwargs, nodes=nodes)

class NodeA(Node):
    def __init__(self, foo: int, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._foo = foo * 2
        
    def as_serialized(self):
        return {"foo": self._foo // 2, **super().as_serialized()}

class NodeB(Node):
    def __init__(self, bar: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._bar = bar + "!"
        
    def as_serialized(self):
        return {"bar": self._bar[:-1], **super().as_serialized()}
```

Note the "subtype" field has changed:

```
demo = {
    "subtype": ("__main__", "NodeA"),
    "foo": 3,
    "nodes": [
        {
            "subtype": ("__main__", "NodeB"),
            "bar": "ghj",
            "nodes": []
        },
        {
            "subtype": ("__main__", "NodeA"),
            "foo": 7,
            "nodes": []
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actually, your code still as a circular dependency. `NodeA` is derived from `Node`. In addition, `NodeA` also has to be imported in the context of `Node` for your `getattr` function call to work. Maybe I am missing something, but how would you put each of the three classes into a separate .py-file and, then, how would you solve the circular import issue which arises (that in my opinion still remains)?

Comment: @s-m-e, how would you use `Node`, `NodeA`, and `NodeB` if you didn't import them somewhere?  Your main (or other) code imports them so it can build a tree.  When you import a module, it gets cached in `sys.modules`.  That's why my code looks up the module in `sys.modules` and then gets the class from the module.  If you imported `NodeA` from "fileA.py", then `getattr(sys.modules["fileA"], "NodeA")` would get the appropriate class. If you want , `Node.from_serialized()` could also load the module if it wasn't already loaded. Look as code for `_Loader` in the `pickle` module.

Comment: Yeah, that's the "run-time loading" / bodging I was referring to. It's kind of ugly and has a tendency to fail in fascinating ways, but yes, I have done this before. It's a valid option after all.

Comment: That should be `_Unpickler` not `_Loader`.

Comment: Thanks. FYI, I just added a context section to my question for further details. See the link to my sketch. Maybe this helps to draw some additional light onto the topic.